# Difference in time between switching of browser tab in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to get the time difference between the switching  of browser tab.By this what I meant to say is we are now on ember web app and I switch to some other tab.Now when I return to ember web app I want to get the time difference of these two event.I am not sure how to attain this.Any lead will help.

Answer (score 0):

Do in controller or compoenent :

```
diff: Ember.computed('endTime',function(){
    let start = this.get('startTime');
    let end = this.get('endTime');    
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(end - start);
    var diffSec = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000)); 
    return diffSec;
  }),
  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    const self = this;    
    Ember.$(window).blur(function(e) {      
        self.set('endTime', new Date());
        });
        Ember.$(window).focus(function(e) {      
        self.set('startTime', new Date());
        });
  }
```

and in corresponding template :

```
Difference in second : {{diff}}
```

Please take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8b263ae10069d36fc368ac74f7724219)